# Spurious cell reordering when collection view is reloaded

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm reloading a collection view, and cell reuse order seems to be non-deterministic.

It's not a problem in itself, but I'm loading images asynchronously with SDWebImage and filtering them with GPUImage (which also works asynchronously, as far as I can tell). The result is nasty flickering, even when the collection view content does not change, because it would almost always swap adjacent cells.

Of course, I can add some synchronous in-memory cache that would have post-processed images, so the image is set before the cell is configured, as opposed to a callback later, but it comes at the expense of needless increase in complexity, which I want to avoid.

**Is there a way to reload individual collection view cells "in place" without collection view cell reuse kicking in?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of full reload, batch updates should be used to insert and delete individual rows. It keeps existing cells in place.

### Before

```
[collectionView reloadData];
```

### After

```
[collectionView performBatchUpdates:^() {
    // Use insertItemsAtIndexPaths, deleteItemsAtIndexPaths,
    // insertSections, deleteSections
    // to add and delete sections and rows
} completion:nil];
```

The downside is that refresh logic can get much more complicated, as you need to diff previous and current data sources.